# How to change bindingParameters type in a node-ibm_db query?

Tags: node.js, db2

I need to improve a query on DB2 casting a bindingParameter from integer to string.

```
db2Conn.query(queryString, [propnum], function(error, success) {...});
```

The result string will be:

```
select * from PROPOSAL where PROPNUM=1234567890 for read only with ur
```

But I would like to be:

```
select * from PROPOSAL where PROPNUM='1234567890' for read only with ur
```

The first one takes at least 7 seconds, the second one takes almost 1 second. How can I say to this package to handle this param like a string?

Comment: Can you provide more code, not just the db2Conn.query? Of what type is PROPNUM?

Comment: @data_henrik PROPNUM is CHAR on DB2 and I take its value from a post request

Comment: Then why is the performance different? In both cases Db2 has to compare a string. Did you measure on a cold and warm buffer...?

Comment: This happen on the production db (warm buffer?). During development (cold buffer?) I had not this difference. Many users reported bad performances and app logs incriminate this query. A test (on Squirrel Client) return these measures: 7 seconds is the best result, sometimes it takes 25 seconds. Then I would like to force the binding parameter to be a string in my script to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your description and the details in the comments I would just do this:

```
db2Conn.query(queryString, [propnum.toString()], function(error, success) {...});
```

The `toString()` converts your input to a string. As an alternative, you could first prepare the statement, then execute it. Depending on the application scenario that is also the preferred way of executing a query.

Comment: I tried and it works without errors. I hope it will work fine also on production. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Once it works, please upvote and mark as answer

Answer (score 0):

There is another solution:

```
db2Conn.query(queryString, [{ParamType:"INPUT", SQLType: "CHAR", "Data": propnum}], function(error, success) {...});
```

https://github.com/ibmdb/node-ibm_db#bindParameters